# Php file_get_contents not working in Local server

Tags: php, macos, localhost, file-get-contents

I enabled php in my MAC osX and normal php codes works fine , but I got one strange error today

```
<?php 
$hi = file_get_contents("https://ojooo.com");
echo $hi;
?>
```

For the above code i get below error on my local server.But above code is working fine on my Hosting.

```
Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14077458:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:reason(1112) in /Library/WebServer/Documents/hi/index.php on line 2

Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Failed to enable crypto in /Library/WebServer/Documents/hi/index.php on line 2

Warning: file_get_contents(https://ojooo.com) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: operation failed in /Library/WebServer/Documents/hi/index.php on line 2
```

the normal `file_get_content(https://yahoo.com);` is working fine.Please some one help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this site you try to call redirects to SSL(https). And then you need the `php_openssl.dll` module. Otherwise its not working.

Edit your active `php.ini` find the line:

`;extension=php_openssl.dll`

and uncomment it.

**Edit:**

you can make an `phpinfo()` and look at the top of the output. There you can see  which `php.ini`file is loaded.

Comment: yea i opened php.ini file !! but do u know the shortcut to find text in terminal ??

Comment: Hey ,,now i get only blank file

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and i finally solved by replace `file_get_contents` with `curl` call.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
$content = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to activate OpenSSL.

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Remove ;

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

in your php.ini file.

Comment: search your php.ini file. run php --ini in your console

Comment: yea i opened php.ini file !! but do u know the shortcut to find text in terminal ??

Answer (score -1):

There appears to be a problem with your servers SSL certificate, if there is even supposed to be one.

Use `$hi = file_get_contents("http://ojooo.com");` instead

Comment: Yea i changed, but still same error...But same code works fine in HOSTING...but not on my local server