# file_get_contents not working on CentOS 7

Tags: php, laravel, centos, firewall, phpoffice

I was using `phpoffice` template processing functionality with Laravel and it worked on `Ubuntu`, `Windows` and `Mac`. The functionality stopped working when I migrated to `centos` server. I figured out that the phpoffice was calling `file_get_contents` to open the template file and it is failing.

So started testing the file_get_contents function.

```
echo file_get_contents('http://my-server-ip-address/api/public/storage/templates/template.docx');
```

Error,

```
ErrorException (E_WARNING)
file_get_contents(http://my-server-ip-address/api/public/storage/templates/template.docx): failed to open stream: Connection timed out
```

php.ini configuration,

```
allow_url_fopen = On // tried  allow_url_fopen = 1 also
```

Tried,

```
user_agent = "PHP"
```

I cannot change the function call to `CURL` approach as this is internally handled in the phpoffice composer package. Is there a solution for this?

I can access the file directly on the browser. No issues with that.

**Edit:**

1. `echo file_get_contents('http://my-ip/api/public/storage/templates/template.docx');`
2. `echo file_get_contents('http://my-domain/api/public/storage/templates/template.docx');`
3. `echo file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/');`
4. `echo file_get_contents('http://localhost/api/public/storage/templates/template.docx');`

Here 1 & 2 not working from the same server which the IP/domain points to but it works from any other systems including local.

**Summary**

Same issue with `wget` and `CURL`.

The server can't find itself using IP or domain but other systems can communicate with server.

The server identifies itself only as `localhost`.

Comment: are you using laravel /?

Comment: @AmitSharma yes

Comment: are you able to access this with a direct hit in the URL ?

Comment: @AmitSharma yes

Comment: Are there two servers involved here, or just one? That is, is the web page you're hitting on the same server as where the code is running (it seems so) or a different one?

Comment: @GregSchmidt same server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [file\_get\_contents - Connection timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189973/file-get-contents-connection-timed-out). Or, perhaps, this, if it’s related to Centos (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189973/file-get-contents-connection-timed-out)

Answer (score 0):

you can give it a try. hope it helps you out.

```
$url= 'https://example.com';

 $arrContextOptions=array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'=>"GET",
        'header'=>"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"
    ) ,
    "ssl"=>array(
          "verify_peer"=>false,
          "verify_peer_name"=>false,
          "allow_self_signed" => true, // or "allow_self_signed" => false,

      ),
  );  

$response = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
```

you can read out all the manual about the stramContext here on the php manual https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: try giving 777 permission to this doc

Comment: Tried that as well

Comment: try enable this extension as well mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13589639/php-file-get-contents-not-working-in-local-server

Comment: enabled extension, no luck.

Comment: could you please provide me the URL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205636/discussion-between-devo-and-amit-sharma).